# I try to have a function that return a string from window.getSelection() contening inline style

Tags: javascript, string

I try to have a function that returns a string from window.getSelection() containing inline style like so:`"<p style='color: red;'>Red text selected</p>"`

I've tried this:

```
var funcToInject = function () {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    return (selection.rangeCount > 0) ? selection.toString(): '';
```

but return a Selection object but I don't know how to handle this.
toString() the selection return just the string "Red text" without the inline style;
What I expect instead is a return string `"<p style='color: red;'>Red text</p>"`.

The end goal is to use this inline string in a chrome extension text field that reads this line to show a Red text, red, or whatever there is in the style applied.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is not the text but the HTML containing the text.

Try This:

```
var funcToInject = function () {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    return (selection.rangeCount > 0) ? selection.baseNode.parentElement.outerHTML : '';
```